# Get item that was popped with MongoDB $pop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

Currently I have this code:

```
while(abc.length < amount){
    collection.update( {username : from }, { $pop: { fieldc: 1 } } );
}
```

But the problem is that I would like to know what items are being removed from fieldc when I do $pop, I can't find a callback to do it and I don't want to get the user's `fieldc` when it starts and then get the difference at the end because what I'm doing won't work that way.
What can I do to find out what item is being popped?

Comment: I would have said "use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)", but it returns the whole document (either after or before the operation), which likely means that it won't work either for whatever you are doing.

Comment: @Philipp I'm working on a transaction system and I need to get the id's of the coins popped from the users account, but what if someone sends him money while this is happening. That's the problem.

Comment: Actually interesting. Have you  checked the response from [`.getLastError()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getLastError/)? Which if **anything** might possibly contain the response. But this does seem to be a single document operation, so there is a better way. See [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Comment: This also seems to be  (at the moment) as single document update. So the other option rings true right now. `.findAndModify()` is an **atomic** update.

Comment: @NeilLunn If I use `.findAndModify()` and while it was updating another process modified the same document will it return the changes from that other process or only from it's self?

Comment: Too broad for a comment. Read the documentation. The answer is there and you have already been given links several times. Look at the comments. The question is a fair one, but the documentation provides a reasonable answer.

Comment: You can pass a set of fields for findAndModify to return.